# Is there a way to convert DataHandler (with zipped content) without creating File object to get InputStream?

Tags: java, stream, java-io, zip

I would like to omit creating `File`. My `DataHandler` Object contains zip file with one entry inside. I need to get properly `InputStream` which could read zipped content.

Actually, my "flow" is as following: DataHandler -> File -> ZipFile -> first ZipEntry.getInputStream().

Is there a way to not create `File/ZipFile` object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is:

```
DataHandler dh = ... 
ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(dh.getInputStream());
ZipEntry entry = zis.getNextEntry();
```

**...and after that `zis` is currently set at the beggining of first zip entry.**

Thanks to @aetheria & @Janoz for `ZipInputStream` hint.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use a [ZipInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html) instead.

EDIT: It depends how your zipped content is stored inside your `DataHandler`.

If it's stored in a byte array...

```
byte[] zippedContent = dataHandler.getContent();
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(zippedContent);
ZipInputStream zipIn = new ZipInputStream(in)
ZipEntry zipEntry = zipIn.getNextEntry();
```

If it provides access to an `InputStream`...

```
ZipInputStream zipIn = new ZipInputStream(dataHandler.getInputStream());
ZipEntry zipEntry = zipIn.getNextEntry();
```

Now you can read the expanded content from the ZipInputStream, as you would any other InputStream.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but how I could fill `byte[] zipContent`? Anyway, I  can't read all bytes at once, henve byte array seems not to be fine.

Comment: ZipEntry also seems not to have `getInputStream` method.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for [`ZipInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html)